# Signal (SIGTERM) not received by subprocess on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess, signals

I have a server that starts a subprocess, and I can manage to do a `send_signal(SIGTERM)` which will kill the process. But not gracefully.
If I call my subprocess from shell (i.e. as a single process), the defined signal handler will kick in and exit gracefully.

server.py:
(so.. from another script I first call `start_app()`, and later `exit_app()`

```
def start_app():
    app = subprocess.Popen("python app.py")

def exit_app():
    p = app.poll()
    if p==None:
        print("Subprocess is alive") # debug
    app.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
```

app.py

```
def exit_signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print("Terminate signal received")
    app.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_signal_handler)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Again, if I call app.py from shell and send a `SIGTERM`signal I get a trace `Terminate signal received` and app closes.
But when app.py is started by server and I call `exit_app` in server, I get a trace `Subprocess is alive` (from server.py) and app is killed but the signal is not caught in app's signalhandler `exit_signal_handler`

EDIT:
It seems `send_signal()` doesn't send a signal **to** the subprocess in the sense that subprocess catches the signal. It send`s a signal for an action to take place on the subprocess:

```
    def send_signal(self, sig):
        """Send a signal to the process
        """
        if sig == signal.SIGTERM:
            self.terminate()
        elif sig == signal.CTRL_C_EVENT:
            os.kill(self.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
        elif sig == signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
            os.kill(self.pid, signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported signal: {}".format(sig))
```

This probably answers my question but I'll leave it open...

Comment: @georgexsh killed = finished, exited, process no longer running on CPU. And `poll()` is done just as a sanity check to see that subprocess is actually alive before sending `SIGTERM`

Comment: so real issue is you haven't seen the message that signal handler should be printed out? try write to file instead?

Comment: @georgexsh hmm... Good point. I see where you're going with this, but stuff that happens in `__main__` gets printed when run as `subprocess()`. I have `print()` there as well but  just haven't included it here.

Comment: you could confirm this by writing log to a file, and check the return value of `app.poll()` is 0 or -15, 0 means a normal exit and the signal handler worked.

Comment: with your new edit, are you using windows?

Comment: The edit is a copy paste of `signal.send_signal()` routine. Yes, windows

Comment: oops, I assumed Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you are using Windows, `SIGTERM` handler is [useless](https://bugs.python.org/issue26350), more [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772001/how-to-handle-the-signal-in-python-on-windows-machine):

> On Windows, the C runtime implements the six signals that are required by standard C: SIGINT, SIGABRT, SIGTERM, SIGSEGV, SIGILL, and SIGFPE.
>
> SIGABRT and SIGTERM are implemented just for the current process.

But you could use `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` as an [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772001/how-to-handle-the-signal-in-python-on-windows-machine).

I.e. create a signal handler in app.py that handles `SIGBREAK`, but send the `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` from the parent. Also, make sure to start your subprocess using `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` (otherwise it will kill the parent as well)

```
app = subprocess.Popen("python app.py", shell=True, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
time.sleep(1)

while 1:
    p = app.poll()
    if p is not None:
        break
    app.send_signal(signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
    time.sleep(2)
```

app.py:

```
exit = False

def exit_signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global exit
    print("Terminate signal received")
    exit = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, exit_signal_handler)
while not exit:
    pass
```

Comment: Maybe I've been unclear, might edit the question. In both cases the application is terminated by `SIGTERM` but when running as subprocess the signal handler in app.py is not called... The application is just terminated promptly

Comment: Nice references. Thing is, if I register `SIGINT` and press ctrl+c on my keyboard, my handler catches the signal... But when run as subprocess, I can't send the signal from script since `send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` throws an error (as seen in my edit). It's all weird

Comment: why you use `SIGINT`?

Comment: Aahhh... You register `SIGBREAK` but send `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`

Comment: Lol, I'll try it first thing in the morning, left laptop at work. I'll get back to you on this in 11h ;)

Comment: But how is one supposed to know that about signals? That `SIGBREAK` and `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` are related?

Comment: then how do you that they don't? you should read all the references first.

Comment: I don't know, I'm just asking how **you** knew that they are related.

Comment: I feel it is not very nice that asking before reading the references.

Comment: Got it! "When the console sends the process a CTRL_C_EVENT or CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, the CRT's handler calls the registered SIGINT or SIGBREAK"

Comment: Man, how do you find all these references haha

Comment: Thanks! Except the `CTRL_C_EVENT` + `SIGBREAK`, this `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` was **key**, without it, it will kill the parent aswell.

Comment: I encountered an issue with how (or actually **when** the signal was processed/handled. Do you have any inputs on that? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48687981/2923755

Comment: @niCkcAMel ok. but I dont any experience with neither QT or window application dev.