# Gracefully terminating a subprocess in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Is there a way to gracefully terminate a subprocess, at any time? That is, before exiting, giving the subprocess time to take action before exiting.

I've tried with `send_signal()` (as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47306805/signal-not-received-by-subprocess) but with no luck)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989942/3474146) would help?  Does it make sense to get the process' `pid` and then use the `pid` to kill the process later on?  Then if that subprocess you're killing is itself a Python script, you could use the `signal` library to [detect the signal interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully) and gracefully die.

Comment: Thing is, I **can** kill the subprocess, in different ways, but all those will promptly end the process.. i.e. not gracefully. In the provided link I tried sending e.g. `SIGTERM` signal, which will kill the process but not gracefully.

Comment: I want to start a subprocess. Some time after (undefined time) I want to kill the subprocess, **but** before the subprocess is killed I want to e.g. notify the subprocess about this. Then, the subprocess can do stuff and kill itself.

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464349/3474146) an example of what you're talking about?  The subprocess receives the `SIGTERM` signal and runs some clean-up function before its death.

Comment: That's not a subprocess. Have a look at my provided link

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look.  But I think I'm a little confused about what type of subprocess we're talking about.  My understanding is that if you run a Python script, it's a process.  If that process executes another Python script (say, using the Python native `subprocess` module) then the child process is a subprocess.  If we agree on that, then the script I linked to is indeed a subprocess, when executed from another Python script.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  If so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772001/how-to-handle-the-signal-in-python-on-windows-machine

Comment: @alex yep windows