# Sending signal to QApplication

Tags: python, qt, subprocess, pyqt5, qapplication

I'm sending a `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` to a QApplication subprocess and the subprocess's handler manages to catch the signal (and perform some magic before exiting). However, when the signal is sent, it is not processed until I interact with the QApplication window (causing it to somehow use CPU cycles LOL), only then will it handle the signal.

E.g.

1. I start QApplication as subprocess
2. I send a `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` (from server that started the subprocess).
3. Nothing happens.
4. I click on any button in the QApplication.
5. It handles the `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` and exits.

I would of course prefer step 5 to take place at step 3.

What's wrong? How would I "refresh" the QApplication or virtualy click a button when it's run in a subprocess? I suspect that the QApplication's main event loop somehow is in idle mode... until the application is interacted with. (?)

**server.py**

```
app = None

def start_app():
    global app

    app = subprocess.Popen("python app.py")

def exit_app():
    global app

    p = app.poll()
    if p==None:
        print("Subprocess is alive") # debug
    app.send_signal(signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
```

**app.py**

```
import sys, signal
from runner import mainWindow

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = None
mw = None

def exit_signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global app, mw

    print("Terminate signal received")
    app.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, exit_signal_handler)

    mw = mainWindow.MainWindow() # this is the Qt window starting
    mw.actionExit.triggered.connect(app.quit)

    sys.exit("Runner exit with code: " + str(app.exec()))
```

Comment: Can you show how you `connect()` the signal .. and where?

Comment: @MohammadKanan It's described in detail here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/47306805/2923755. If you see something important there I can edit the question

Comment: Not much familiar with Py. my understanding however is that when you start Qapp subprocess it would start its (blocking) event loop (?) So your signal is being blocked, what I can't understand is why pressing arbitrary button exits or deblocks that event loop!

Comment: I asked where you are connecting your Signal/Slot because it could be related, if the connect() is done inside the Qapp sub process then its supposed to work

Comment: @MohammadKanan Ok so, there's no `connect()` involved here, the signal is caught by `exit_signal_handler(signal, frame)` in app.py in the link I provided

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: @Murphy clever.  [ihaveaddedco.de/sohelp](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I do not know if your example has trimmed several things but I notice that app is a local variable in server.py, your example is not a [mcve], it can not be verified since it is imcomplete

Comment: @eyllanesc . Yes, highly trimmed. I've edited now to include more code

Comment: This is still not a [mcve]. `server.py` does nothing when started on my system (of course, any start code is missing), and `app.py` is missing the `runner` module.

Comment: @Murphy I see your point, but if one is to throw a downvote because not all rules are **literally** met, then you'd have to downvote the majority of questions on SO. That's not to justify my "mistake", it's just a fact. Furthermore, since I suspect something is going on in the QApplication's main event loop, which is somehow paused and only resumed upon interaction, I figure someone with enough knowledge will spot the issue without having to have access to all the code in question

Comment: You haven't read the provided links, have you? You're wasting people's time.

Comment: @Murphy and you didn't read what I said. You know, you're not obliged to revisit and comment. You've thrown your downvote, provided links.. I mean you're done. Thank you for the effort but do not revisit.

Comment: could the QApp run within a thread? I *guess* it blocked on a sys call and signal in windows can not break blocking sys call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `Qtimer()` in app.py for poll reasons seems to do the trick. Any signals sent will be processed every second when `pollMe()`is called by `Qtimer`

```
import sys, signal
from runner import mainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore           #<---- NEW
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = None
mw = None

def pollMe():                      # <--- NEW
    timerPoll.start(1000)

def exit_signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global app, mw

    print("Terminate signal received")
    app.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, exit_signal_handler)

    timerPoll = QtCore.QTimer()        #<---- NEW
    timerPoll.timeout.connect(pollMe)
    timerPoll.start(1000)

    mw = mainWindow.MainWindow() # this is the Qt window starting
    mw.actionExit.triggered.connect(app.quit)

    sys.exit("Runner exit with code: " + str(app.exec()))
```