# Python, How to handle signal in Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, signals, signal-handling

This is **specifically for Windows**, I don't have this issue on linux based systems.

So, I have a program that creates subprocesses when running it. 
These subprocesses will terminate correctly if the program exits normally, or even with exceptions or ctrl+c event, by using `try` and `KeyboardInterrupt` and `finally` in `if __name__ == '__main__':`

However, if I kill the program in the middle, I'm talking about killing it in `PyCharm`, using the `STOP` button. Those subprocesses will not terminate. I'm not exactly sure what signal this `STOP` button sends on Windows.

I tried signal handling using `signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)`. It doesn't work, I have tried `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, (`SIGKILL`, `CTRL_C_EVENT`, `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` don't work in signal handler. ). None of them works. I have also read this post: [How to handle the signal in python on windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772001/how-to-handle-the-signal-in-python-on-windows-machine)

How can I gracefully exit in this scenario? This `STOP` button in PyCharm scenario.

Comment: Have you tried to `Right-click` on the run-bar next to `Run` > `Close All`?

Comment: There's also using [`os.kill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.kill)`(p.pid, SIGINT)` within your handler.

Comment: If the stop button terminates the process directly, there's nothing graceful about this. The best you can do is to add your process to a Job object that disallows breakaway, so all child processes will be in the job. Flag the  job as kill-on-close. Keep the job handle open in the main program. Then if the main program gets terminated, the job will be closed, and at least all processes in the job are also terminated.