# Which signals are supported in windows and how they can be catch and handled in python?

Tags: signals

I don't understand the difference like some signal are defined for linux some for windows can you tell me the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific, but I suggest reading:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html
- https://maruel.ca/post/python_windows_signal/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792192/1424462