# How can I run function before the process killed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, signals, terminate

I have a python script. How can I do something before the process will be terminated?
For example I want to print something on display or write to log file.
OS: Windows 11 x64
python version: 3.8.10
I tried this one, but it doesn't work:

```
import signal
import sys
import time


def handle_iterrupt():
    print("Handling interrupt")
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_iterrupt)
    for x in range(100):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Update:
If the process is terminated from the task manager, or `cmd` is closed, or the process is terminated with `taskkill /F /PID {PID}`, I want to run some function or write something to a log file.

Comment: First of all, `handle_iterrupt` takes two arguments and you have provided 0, so at the very least you need to modify your function definition or it will never work. Second, what are you doing to generate a `SIGTERM` interrupt? Just try `kill task_number`.

Comment: I don't think the `signal` stuff works on Windows (i.e. it's for Unix and Unix-like systems only).

Comment: @martineau
If the process is terminated from the task manager, or cmd is closed, or the process is terminated with `taskkill /F /PID {PID}`, I want to run some function or write something to a log file.

Comment: I don't know about those specific scenarios — i.e. which ones cause "normal interpreter termination" — but the [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) module might work in at least some of them. Putting almost the whole program in a `main()` function and calling it inside a `try` / `except` might also work in some of the cases.

Comment: Turns out that ***some*** types of signals do work on the Windows OS — in the last paragraph in the documentation for [`signal.signal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal) it says "On Windows, `signal()` can only be called with `SIGABRT`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, `SIGINT`, `SIGSEGV`, `SIGTERM`, or `SIGBREAK`." There's a list of what each of those mean [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#module-contents).

Comment: There's some [more information](https://pymotw.com/3/signal/index.html) about using the `signal` module including examples of using it from the excellent "Python 3 Module of the Week" book and [website](https://pymotw.com/3/) (since you apparently don't even know how to write a *signal handler* function).

Comment: There some good information on how signals are implemented on Windows in the answers to the question [How to handle a signal.SIGINT on a Windows OS machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772001/how-to-handle-a-signal-sigint-on-a-windows-os-machine)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run code when a process is terminated by `kill -9` or `taskkill /F`, as the operating system will directly kill the process, leaving no opportunity to handle it.

You can handle other signals that lead to process termination.

On POSIX systems, these include `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGQUIT`, and `SIGHUP`.

On Windows, the signals are `SIGINT`, `SIGBREAK`, `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`, and `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`.

It's really tricky to handle these signals correctly, especially for cross-platform applications.

To address this, I have created a package called [safe-exit](https://pypi.org/project/safe-exit/).

The documentation can be found here: https://safe-exit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/