# Implement exit routine in python executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, exit

I have created a executable of a python application using the library `pyinstaller`.

When the `*.exe` is started via a double click a window with the python console starts and the application begins to run.
Now when I close the app using the **X** in the top right corner of every window I want to execute some code before the application finally stops.

Here is a snippet of my code which gives a example of what I'm trying to do:

```
def exit_handler():
    # This code should get executed before the application finally terminates
    print("I want this to print")
    sys.exit()

def main(*args):
    atexit.register(exit_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_handler)
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Unfortunately using the `signal` statements and the `atexit` library does not work when building the executable using `pyinstaller`.
Does anyone knows a solution for that issue?

Update: I'm working on a windows OS

Comment: How did you verify that they do now work? I have no expertise there, I am just wondering if the print statement might only be lost and not logged correctly, e.g. would some other method like creating a file actually work which verifies that the code actually did run.

Comment: *Strong* suggestion: Either: 1) Pass `file=sys.stderr` to `print`, sending the message to `stderr` instead of `stdout` (so the output is unbuffered by default), or, if the message is logically not a log/warning, 2) Explicitly pass `flush=True` to `print` (so `stdout`'s buffers are flushed immediately). I'd also recommend not using a handler that calls `sys.exit()` to `atexit.register`; if any *other* exit handler registered later raises an exception, this will replace it, so the program exits with exit code 0 (success) instead of a non-zero failure code.

Comment: For the latter suggestion, you could just replace `atexit.register(exit_handler)` with `atexit.register(print, "I want this to print", file=sys.stdout)` (assuming `exit_handler` is really just a `print` and a call to `sys.exit`).

Comment: @Daraan I do not use a print statement there, I use a log statement which should write something in a log file but this does not happen.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes this may be a solution for the print statement but in reality I want to execute a clean up code and write information into a log file

Comment: Don't call exit in the exit handler registered with atexit.register() Use a different function to handle the signals as they require a different function type

Comment: @DarkKnight thanks for the hint I'll remove this statement. But this does not reach the wanted behaviour.

Comment: @kamaru510: Not a solution, but someone else having issues with PyInstaller signal handling appears to have [written some test code and documentation on the problem](https://github.com/brettdh/pyinstaller-signal-handling/). It specifically talks about stuff *other* than `SIGTERM`/`SIGINT` being a problem, but it might help track down what's going wrong for you.

Comment: Can we safely assume that you're not trying to run this on Windows?

Comment: @DarkKnight: I'd kind of expect it to be Windows, given the `.exe` extension, and double-clicking to launch a terminal like that... OP should be specific about OS target(s) since signals are often non-portable.

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, on Windows, closing the console hosting a Python process sends `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, which [is translated into a `SIGBREAK`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792192/364696), not `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`. If you're on Windows (which is [the only place `SIGBREAK` is supported according to Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGBREAK)), you'd want to handle that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger OP should not expect SIGTERM to work on Windows as it would on a Unix type system

Comment: @kamaru510: Your code, as written, does not work even without PyInstaller involved. 1) You shouldn't call `sys.exit()` in the `atexit` handler (as mentioned), and 2) The handler for a signal must accept two positional arguments, and your handler does not. The combined effect is that: 1) The signal handler never runs, and 2) The exception raised when it fails to run is dumped to `stderr` and otherwise ignored because the `SystemExit` raised by `sys.exit()` in the `atexit` handler replaces it. Provide a [MCVE] that actually reproduces the problem (works without PyInstaller, fails with).

Comment: Yes I'm working on Windows and the code provided by me works fine if I call the main.py directly instead of building an executable via pyinstaller

Answer (score 1):

Try this on a Unix type system:

```
from atexit import register
from time import sleep
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIGTERM

def end():
    print('Goodbye')

def handler(*_):
    print('Signalled')
    exit()

register(end)

signal(SIGINT, handler)
signal(SIGTERM, handler)

sleep(5)
```

Notice the difference between the signal handler and the atexit function.

Run this program and wait for at least 5 seconds. The output will be:

```
Goodbye
```

Run this program and interrupt it (e.g., Ctrl-C) before 5 seconds has elapsed. The output will be:

```
^CSignalled
Goodbye
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I cannot move to a Unix type system with this application. It is designed to work on windows hosts

Comment: @kamaru510 In that case I suggest you research the viability of trying to use SIGINT and SIGTERM signals on Windows. If you try the code in this answer on a Windows system and it doesn't behave in the way I describe then you'll know that your approach is not portable

Comment: The code that I posted above works on my windows machine but only if I start the main.py script. It works not when I start the executable made from that application. In my point of View this issue is related to `pyinstaller`. I need to research what kind of signal is sent when I close the open console via the **X**

Comment: @kamaru510 The code you posted in your question is flawed as explained in the comments

Comment: Sure, that might be and I already improved it with the suggestions I received. But even though it worked. It also worked when running the executable but only if I terminate the app using CTRL+C.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for my issue. Like in most cases the exact reading of the docs brings the solution. Thanks to everyone for their effort.

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/feature-notes.html#signal-handling-in-console-windows-applications-and-onefile-application-cleanup